# Sonarqube 5.1.1 issue author is displayed but not the assignee

Tags: svn, groovy, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm using sonarqube 5.1.1 with Java, pmd, ldap and svn plugins. Using ant and jenkins for building purposes.

After sonarqube analysis I can see that the issues are displayed with the name of the author in left-side. I can even search by the author and see the issues by that author.

But they are not automatically assigned. (I'm not using issue assign plugin because sonar source developers say that it is not compatible with 5.* versions)
Is there any easy way to do this. Your help will be highly appreciated.

I've found this groovy script for the purpose [here](http://webdizz.name/blog/2013/12/19/automatic-assignment-of-issues-in-sonarqube/comment-page-1/). Is it any good??

Thank you.

Comment: An issue can be automatically assigned only if the author matches the login, email or any extra SCM accounts of a SQ user. Can you check this?

Comment: Yeah. we are using same user name and emails to login to both. @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam

Comment: Anything in the logs (on server side) that would mention that there are several users who can match a given SCM account (= author)? This is one of the reasons why an issue would not be assigned.

Comment: my logs/sonar.log is blank. (It populates only when sonar starts and stops)  Can you direct me to the place where I have to look please. @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam My ANT build log have no such entry.

Comment: What does the following SQL request return? "SELECT * FROM USERS where LOGIN like '%XXX%' OR EMAIL like '%XXX%' OR SCM_ACCOUNTS like '%XXX%';" where XXX is the name of the author on the left-side of the issues.

Comment: I searched using "nm40358" who was the author. @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam

| 73 | nm40358 | Nilan Mihindukulasooriya | nilan.mihindukulasooriya@ae.com | c51e5cef0134178709d90324dccf27cf536272ac | 2efd95b2c9f8571a38c1d47c5ed68ccbf72ec8d3 | NULL           | NULL                      |      1 | 1438141158321 | 1438238234642 | NULL
But when i put the name which is displayed in the left side (which is the first name and last name of the person) it returns an empty set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84681/discussion-between-nilan59-and-fabrice-sonarsource-team).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the directions given in the comments.

By getting the SCM author name (On the left side of Sonarqube code view) and add the exact name as a SCM account.

```
Settings -> Security -> Users -> Edit -> Add SCM account
```